# How can I use a variable to change the type of css style using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, variables, styles

I created this Vanilla Javascript function for a parallax effect on my website's landing page and it is pretty efficient but could be one step better.

```
function parallaxTop(direction, id, startingNumber, scrollVariable){
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.top = (startingNumber + (scrolled * scrollVariable)) + 'px';
}

function parallaxLeft(direction, id, startingNumber, scrollVariable){
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.left = (startingNumber + (scrolled * scrollVariable)) + 'px';
}

window.onscroll = function() {
    parallaxTop('element1', 0, 0.5);
    parallaxLeft('element2', 200, -0.25);
}
```

I want to know if there is any way I could use a variable to select which type of css attribute is being changed. This would be my best guess but I can't find a solution.

```
function parallax(direction, id, startingNumber, scrollVariable){
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.direction = (startingNumber + (scrolled * scrollVariable)) + 'px';
}

window.onscroll = function() {
    parallax('top','element1', 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this

```
element.style.direction = (startingNumber + (scrolled * scrollVariable)) + 'px';
```

to

```
element.style[direction] = (startingNumber + (scrolled * scrollVariable)) + 'px';
```

Comment: try this ``element.style[`${direction}`]``